# How to set up Eclipse for Java Web Development with Spring?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, ide

I'm following [this tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/overview.html) about Spring development which describes that to setup Eclipse, use Eclipse Europa, with Web Tools Platform (WTP), and Project Spring IDE Project.

However, Eclipse Europa site says that its about a project from 2007, and the Spring IDE project website seems dead / broken as well. So that article might be out of date.

I've downloaded the 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' package from Eclipse's downloads package. Is that sufficient or should I get Europa, Web Tools Platform, and Spring IDE?

Any other plugins/packages that make Spring development easier with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the [Spring ToolSuite](http://www.springsource.org/sts) is the canonical Eclipse/Spring package.

Europa is quite old; not sure why it'd be under consideration. IIRC Juno is current.

Comment: Thanks. The article must be outdated. And what about the Web tools platform, not needed?

Comment: @ClickUpvote AFAICT the article is from 2007-2008. WTP would come in the EE build, I would *assume* it comes with the full STS download, but I don't know that. Since developing a Spring web app uses several standard JEE web artifacts, it would be quite odd if it didn't.

Comment: Do you know of any more up to date alternative to the article? Just wondering.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Minor Google searching: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/, etc. There's some new stuff in 3.2 worth checking out. The Spring MVC docs themselves are quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts) for my last couple of projects and it's perfectly suited.